# Can WordPress updates take down site functions?

Tags: plugins, updates

I just received new assignments here at work, now i'm work with Wordpress, but is the first contact, i entered the site settings and saw that the situation is chaotic, WordPress is still at version 5.7.8 and there are at least 20 more plugin updates to be made.

I would like to know if i update Wordpress and the plugins the site will crash?

Comment: No one can answer this authoritatively, as every site is different, but 5.7.8 isn't very old. I'd suggest you make the updates on a development environment and check that first.

Comment: Of course!!!
Thanks for idea, i will download everything and put it in a test environment, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments a perfect prediction is not possible, but: I've seen tons of similar scenarios and almost all of them failed the update. With the number of plugins your site is using, it is very likely that at least one won't be compatible with a newer WP, so create a test environment first is the only secure way to upgrade this.

Comment: thank you my friend!
that's exactly what i did, several elements of the site stopped working correctly and there were other details that i couldn't use in the same way, so i went through each plugin updating individually and adjusting to the updated wp.